# assign unique group to identical rows

Tags: r

This is a simplified version of the dataframe I have:

```
structure(list(a = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
    b = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
    c = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor")), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c"), row.names = c("id1", "id2", "id3"), class = "data.frame")
```

In this df, the row.names are the unique IDs (I know it breaks the rules of tidy data).

In the example, we can see that row id1 and rowid2 are duplicates.

What I want to do is identify that they are duplicates, and assign a unique group name to those duplicates. Please note however, there will be multiple rows that are duplicates to each to other.

My desired output would be:

```
ID_NAME  A B C GROUP
row_id1  A B A   1
row_id2  A B A   1
row_id3  A A A   2
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

Sample of my original data:

```
dput(head(temp))
structure(list(name = c("3 - ПЛАСТ  ДОО   С.МУРТИНО  Друштво за производство,трговија и услуги увоз-извоз", 
"FABRIKA ZA OPREMA I DELOVI FOD DOOEL NOVACI AD ELEM SKOPJE", 
"Tрговско друштво за трговија на големо и мало и превоз СЕЈ-ПРОМ  Охрид ДОО", 
"АВТ ИНТЕРНАТИОНАЛ ДОО СКОПЈЕ   Друштво за производство,трговија и услуги", 
"АГНЕСА  ДООЕЛ  БИТОЛА Друштво за производство услуги и трговија на големо и мало", 
"АГРАР ТРЕЈД ДООЕЛ Велес"), h_interni_procent = c(0.02, 0.01, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.015), h_interni_iznos_od = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), h_interni_iznos_do = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), h_interni_min_iznos = c(12, 
10, 10, 6, 10, 10), h_internet_pp53_min_iznos = c(NA, NA, 2, 
NA, NA, NA), h_kibs_procent = c(0.015, 0.015, 0.015, NA, NA, 
0.015)), .Names = c("name", "h_interni_procent", "h_interni_iznos_od", 
"h_interni_iznos_do", "h_interni_min_iznos", "h_internet_pp53_min_iznos", 
"h_kibs_procent"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000220788>)
```

Comment: "we can see that row id1 and rowid3 are duplicates." - how can we see that?

Comment: @docendodiscimus i meant id1 and id2. sorry for the typo. i just edited the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a column from the row names, then grouped by columns a, b, c, get the `.GRP`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, keep.rownames = TRUE)[, GROUP := .GRP, by = .(a, b, c)][]
```

With the new example

```
temp[, GROUP := .GRP, by = c(names(temp)[3:7])]
```

Comment: For my original data I get: Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(cat1), , `:=`(GROUP, .GRP), by = .(3:7)) : 
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (5). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (251).

Comment: @Prometheus  Perhaps you need `by = c(3:7)`

Comment: @Prometheus  IN your new example, there are columns that are only NAs and some are floating point

Answer (score 1):

This code will produce your desired data frame. I'm moving the unique ID into a new column, because the merge operation will overwrite your rownames.

```
b <- unique(a)
b$group <- 1:nrow(b)
a$id <- rownames(a)
c <- merge(a,b)
```

If desired, you can move the IDs back to the row names.

```
rownames(c) <- c$id
c$id <- NULL
```